# Move to specific position in TextFlow JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, textflow

I'm having a `TextFlow` inside a `StackPane` which is inside a `ScrollPane`. I'm adding text with different colors to this `TextFlow`

```
Text txt = new Text(msg);
txt.setFill(Paint.valueOf(color));
txtFlow.getChildren().add(txt);
```

I want to scroll to a some specific point in the textflow.

e.g. First text that is in blue color.

I know I can get the text and check the color. But how can I scroll down to that specific position?

Can I achieve that sort of functionality through the `TextFlow`?
Simply I'm trying to build up a diff view in `JavaFX`. And want to travel through the diffs.

Answer (score 1):

I would take a ListView and put some stackpanes or directly the texts in it.

```
Text content = new Text("Custom Text");
content.setFill(Color.valueOf(yourcolor));   
ListView<Text> list = new ListView<Text>();
list.add(content);
```

Because...
there's a void `scrollTo()` where you can scroll to the item directly by the Text object or to the item by the index (int).

To get a transparent background on the listview you can use:

```
list.setStyle("-fx-background-color: transparent;");
```

I hope this helped you.
I'm sorry if I missunderstood your question.

Peace

Answer (score 1):

Use one of the free styledtext-editors - they all are using ListView or VirtualView internally. See https://github.com/TomasMikula/RichTextFX/wiki/JavaFX-Controls-for-Code-Editing for examples